# How do I create a keyboard event that lets me only use the backspace and numbers (on top of keyboard and numpad)?

Tags: javascript

```
function handleSpinnerInput(event) {

    var keyID = event.keyCode
    if (keyID < 48 || keyID > 57 ) {
        /*
         * If it isn't a number, pretend the key was never pressed at all. This
         * key range works for both the number pad and the numbers on the top of
         * the keyboard. I've tested this on IE, Firefox, and Chrome to verify
         * it works on the latest version. However, I need this to work on Firefox v.31.
         */
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using the onkeydown() function to invoke on an input field but only the top number of the keyboard work and it doesn't even let me type the backspace in the older version. I see that the numpad keycodes are 96-105 and the backspace keycode is 46. how would I include that in my conditional and should I set it to ignore keycodes that are not the ones specified?

EDIT: the code in top worked with the onkeypress() function but I have since changed it to onkeydown() since it didnt work on older firefox.

EDIT:
function handleSpinnerInput(event) {

```
var keyCode = event.keyCode ;
if(!(Number(keyCode) >= 0 && Number(keyCode) <= 9) && keyCode != 'Backspace') 

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener('keydown', handleSpinnerInput)

function handleSpinnerInput(event) {
  if(!(Number(event.key) >= 0 && Number(event.key) <= 9) && event.key != 'Backspace') // Checks whether the key is different from the number or backspace
     event.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

**OR**

```js
function handleSpinnerInput(event) {
  console.log(event.keyCode)
  let isNumber = (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 || event.keycode <= 105)
  let backspace = event.keyCode == 46
  if(!isNumber && !backspace)
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="handleSpinnerInput(event)">
```

Doubts? comment

Comment: It worked beautifully on your example but unfortunately im not sure it it handled the Number casting of my keycode and the backspace still didnt work for me. the keyboard numbers are from 48-57, the keypad number are from 96-105, and the backspace keycode is 46. Is there a way that I can only accept these characters (would i just remove the event.preventDefault and change return to true?) and just ignore all other keycodes that are pressed?

Comment: In your example you are dealing with key codes, in mine I am dealing with the 'name' of the key

Comment: Show how you did it in your code by editing the question

Comment: btw, yes to do using the code, but it would be a little bigger and less elegant, the way I did it is more practical, but if you insist on wanting to use the key code I can edit my answer

Comment: i have just put my changes in my edit of the question. and thank you again for all the help! im using the onkeydown() with my handleSpinnerInput method so im not sure if i need keyCodes but I prefer your method if it can work

edit: for clarification of invoking onkeydown i meant like this:
<p:spinner onkeydown="handleSpinnerInput(event)"/>

Comment: I will add in my answer an alternative to handleSpinnerInput using keycode, if it doesn't work for you let me know. (I will use the codes you entered)

Comment: Hey just wanted to update you and say thank you again for all of the help! I used the event.key instead of the keycode and it ended up working when I cleared the cache for the old version of Firefox, thanks again!